# Problems in installing the LabVIEW 2023Q1 Community Edition on my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am trying to install the LabVIEW 2023Q1 Community Edition on my Ubuntu 20.04 by following the instructions in the following ni link

https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YGwsCAG&l=en-TR

When I submit the following instruction:

```
$ sudo apt install ni-labview-2023-community_23.1.0.49229-0+f77-ubuntu2204_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.list’' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package ni-labview-2023-community_23.1.0.49229-0+f77-ubuntu2204_all.deb
```

I have tried several suggestions to let Ubuntu locate the labView package, but I was not successful so far.

Alternatively, I have also tried to install the LabView Community addition on my Ubunto 20.04 using the following command:
$ sudo dpkg -i ni-labview-2023-community_23.1.0.49229-0+f77-ubuntu2204_all.deb

It took a few seconds to receive the following result:

```
(Reading database ... 396755 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ni-labview-2023-community_23.1.0.49229-0+f77-ubuntu2204_all.deb ...
Unpacking ni-labview-2023-jammy-community (23.1.0.49229-0+f77) over (23.1.0.49229-0+f77) ...
Setting up ni-labview-2023-jammy-community (23.1.0.49229-0+f77) ...
```

Although the command was executed successfully, LabView was not installed on my Ubuntu.

I would be very pleased to receive any comment to overcome this problem and install the LabView Community edition successfully.

Comment: Your first `apt` command told it to look for a package in your sources which it didn't find, as you didn't tell it to use the package you intended as you didn't provide path for it. Your second command is without the complete output, so I'll suggest you read that, but you're trying to use a package created for *jammy* or 22.04; so problems with it could be expected.

Comment: You just need to read the guide you linked to (Step 4 and following). The package you installed successfully added the software source, now run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install ni-labview-2023-pro`.

Comment: Thanky very much for your kind reply. The LabView installation package that I tried to run was actually under the same directory where I ran the sudo apt command:              
ni-labview-2023-community_23.1.0.49229-0+f77-ubuntu2204_all.deb

Comment: Fine, but you used a package name, not a path name. `sudo apt install ./ni-labview-2023-community_23.1.0.49229-0+f77-ubuntu2204_all.deb` would have worked as expected. Looks like the guide is wrong in this point. But remind, it just adds the software source, it doesn't install `labview`.

Comment: I tried $ sudo apt install ./ni-labview-2023-community_23.1.0.49229-0+f77-ubuntu2204_all.deb which ran OK but didnt install the LabView as expected. Any further suggestions to install the LabView are welcome